# When trying to open a .java file from windows explorer I get a "No project found to open file in" error message

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

So, when I double click a file in windows explorer, Intellij fires up, but instead of just showing me the file I want to see, shows up the following message:

[image]

I think I get what it means: it means this given .java file isn't associated with an Intellij project.

That's actually true, but even so I'd like to be able to open the file and see it with syntax highlighting and such.

How to overcome this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you open the file from inside IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes. From intellij it does just what I'd expect it to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known limitation which we plan to address in the future versions to allow opening and editing individual files without project context.

Please [watch/vote the related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-1398).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you <strike>can't</strike>can by default. I'm assuming you are opening downloaded files or such. What I would is create a project (`Scrapbook` for example is a good name) on desktop and I would put/download the file I want to see in the corresponding src folder. That way when I'm clicking it would open properly.

Most of the syntax highlight and such goodness of idea comes from a proper project setup (proper JDK paths, libraries, etc).

Comment: Erm. I get your point. But seems more like a ugly work-around than actually a solution to this problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It's a workaround for sure :). But i doubt you can do more than that :(.